in p5.js, how to display information of a datapoint when the mouse is hovered over it
Adding function for hover and changing draw function
I want to display the information of the datapoint when the mouse is hovered over the point. I tried adding a function and updated my draw function. It didn't do anything. Even if I hover over the point, it does not show me any details.
Even after adding them, I do not see the details of the datapoints when I hover over them. I am not even getting any error messages
here is the code for my sketch.js
let table;
let genres = {};

function preload() {
    console.log("Attempting to load CSV file...");
    table = loadTable('/tmdb_5000_movies.csv', 'csv', 'header', loadSuccess, loadError);
}

function loadSuccess() {
    console.log("CSV loaded successfully");
}

function loadError() {
    console.error("Failed to load CSV file.");
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth * 2.5, windowHeight * 2.5);
    handleData();
    noLoop();
    console.log(table);
}

function handleData() {
    for (let i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
        let row = table.getRow(i);

        // Retrieve data from the row with default values
        let title = row.getString("original_title");
        let popularity = row.getNum("popularity");
        let revenue = row.getNum("revenue");
        let genreStr = row.getString("genres");

        // Parse genre string into an array
        let genreArr = JSON.parse(genreStr).map(g => g.name);

        // Create a new movie instance
        let movie = new Movie(title, popularity, revenue);

        // Add the movie to the corresponding genres
        for (let i = 0; i < genreArr.length; i++) {
            const g = genreArr[i];
            if (!genres[g]) {
                genres[g] = new Genre(g); // Create a new genre if it doesn't exist
            }
            genres[g].addMovie(movie); // Add the movie to the genre
        }
    }

    // Log the genres to check if they were populated correctly
    console.log(genres);
}

function draw() {
    background(123);
    let genreList = Object.keys(genres);
    let rows = int(genreList.length / 3);
    let colWidth = width / 3;
    let rowHeight = height / rows;

    for (let i = 0; i < genreList.length; i++) {
        let genre = genres[genreList[i]];
        let x = (i % 3) * colWidth + colWidth / 2;
        let y = int(i / 3) * rowHeight + rowHeight / 2;

        genre.display(x, y);
    }

    // Check for hover over any movie data point
    let hoveredMovie = getHoveredMovie();
    if (hoveredMovie) {
        fill(255);
        textSize(16);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        text(hoveredMovie.title, mouseX, mouseY - 10); // Display the movie title slightly above the mouse
    }
}

function getHoveredMovie() {
    let genreList = Object.keys(genres);
    for (let i = 0; i < genreList.length; i++) {
        let genre = genres[genreList[i]];
        for (let movie of genre.movies) {  // Assuming genre.movies is an array of movies
            let x = movie.x;  // Assuming movie x position is stored
            let y = movie.y;  // Assuming movie y position is stored
            let size = movie.getStarSize(); // Get the size of the star (point)

            // Check if mouse is within the radius of the movie point
            if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y) < size / 2) {
                return movie;
            }
        }
    }
    return null; // Return null if no movie is hovered over
}


It's best to hardcode in tmdb_5000_movies.csv or at least provide a snippet so it's easier to run your code. Thanks.
